How to hide the Scrollbar while using a Modal from LwC?
I have certain contents under body, but as the contents increases a scrollbar starts to appear as expected. But is there a way to hide it and still the modal is scrollable?
If there's any or anything similar please let me know. Thanks
<lightning-modal-header></<lightning-modal-header>
<lightning-modal-body></<lightning-modal-body>
<lightning-modal-footer></<lightning-modal-footer>


You can hide scroll bar of lightning-modal-body but keep scrollable inside it.
Let me provide sample code:
// It will works for chrome, safari and edge
lightning-modal-body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent;
}

// It will works for Firefox
lightning-modal-body {
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

// It will keep scrollable inside lightning-modal-body
lightning-modal-body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

